# Can I update arrays in a batch?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Per the Firestore docs, I can add to an array:

> regions: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion("greater_virginia")

And I can update a field through a batch:

> batch.update(sfRef, {"population": 1000000});

But can I add to an array through a batch? Something like:

```
batch.update(userDoc, "arrayField": newElement)
```

e.g. I want to update 5 user documents. Each user document contains an array of tags and I want to push a new tag to each.

I cannot find any documentation on this - do I really need to create a transaction that reads the current value of the array and then writes the value back with the new tag?

Comment: Did you try combining arrayUnion with batch.update?

Answer (score 2):

for Android, here is how to update an array

```
  batch.update(ref, "myArrayFruits", FieldValue.arrayUnion("apple"))
```

Comment: This seems like basicly exactly the same as the other answer. How exactly is this different/better?

Comment: it is different because it is Android. I struggled to find this for an hour and decided to post it here for others.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Doug for dignifying my question with a fair comment.

batch.update(sfRef, {regions:firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion("greater_virginia")});